# How do multiply each item in one list, with every item in second list, outputting to a DataFrame table?

Tags: python, dataframe

```
list 1 = [1, 2, 3]
list 2 = [1, 2, 3]

d = {'1': [1, 2, 3], '2': [2, 4, 6], '3': [3, 6, 9] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d,
    index=['1', '2', '3'])
```

I want it to end up like the DataFrame after multiplying each item in list 1 to every item in list 2.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please see the guide to [ask]. When asking a question, be sure to always try to do the thing you are asking about, and look for guides on this site and others, and then show us what you've tried and what's not working. If you're running into errors, please provide the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback). We're not here to write your code for you, but we can definitely help debug if you get stuck. Good luck!

Comment: Looks like you've already done it, no?

Comment: No, because I wanted it calculated.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a case for numpy broadcasting.

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = [1, 2, 3]
>>> B = [1, 2, 3]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(A) * np.array(B)[:, None])
>>> df
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  2  4  6
2  3  6  9
```

Comment: ````A = [500000, 1000000, 1500000]
B = [5000000, 10000000, 15000000]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(A) * np.array(B)[:, None])

df````
This gave me a negative number

Comment: @user70282 Can't reproduce, works as expected for me.

Comment: Super weird. My numbers are fine when I use the small digits, but I get this with the larger numbers


{0:  329033728,   658067456,   987101184}
{1: 658067456, 1316134912,  1974202368}
{2:  987101184,  1974202368, -1333663744}